# Laplacian eigenvalue problem for systems coupled along the boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, elliptic-pde, eigenvalues, laplacian

I am looking for references on eigenvalue problems for systems of the following type:

Let $\Omega$ be the region enclosed by a right triangle with legs $\Gamma_1$, $\Gamma_2$, and hypotenuse $\Gamma_3$, and set $\Gamma=\partial \Omega= \Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \cup \Gamma_3$. Now consider the following system of eigenvalue problems with unknown functions $u_1$ and $u_2$,

\begin{align*}
\Delta u_1&= \lambda u_1  \\
\Delta u_2&= \lambda u_2 \quad \text{ in $\Omega$} \\ 
\end{align*}

and boundary conditions

\begin{align*}
\text{on } \Gamma_1 \begin{cases}
u_1& =0 \\ 
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}n}u_2& =0
\end{cases} 
\\
\text{on } \Gamma_2 
\begin{cases}
u_2& =0 \\ 
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}n}u_1& =0 \\
\end{cases}
\\
\text{on } \Gamma_3 \begin{cases}
u_1-u_2& =0 \\ 
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}n}(u_1+u_2)& =0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Some things to note,

- This problem does have a nice set of solutions, with eigenvalues behaving like those of standard self-adjoint elliptic operators. This is actually no coincidence: the pairs of solutions correspond to the functions in the eigenspaces of the Laplacian acting on the square, which transform according to the two dimensional irreducible representation of its isometry group $D_8$.
- On the surface, this kind of problem seems to be related to transmission eigenvalue problems, but in this case, we want the eigenvalues to agree while allowing the boundary condition to be somewhat twisted. Perhaps someone knows how to adapt the techniques for transmission eigenvalues to this kind of problem?
- It is not clear to me how to write this kind of problem in a variational formulation. Any tips?